# running a task on particular datetime?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am wondering how to write a proper code for runnning a job on particular date on Firebase.

For cron-type job, I know these situation should be realized as follows:

```js
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('5 11 * * *')
  .timeZone('America/New_York') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
  .onRun((context) => {
  console.log('This will be run every day at 11:05 AM Eastern!');
  return null;
});
```

but this for "repeated" job and not for "one-time" job.

Is there any way to run particular job on a particular date using Firebase?

Thanks!

Comment: I found a simular question here but I was unable to solve with it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003747/schedule-cloud-function-at-specific-date-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a great answer here by myself.

https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a